# Bouncy castle security provider doesn't load under Java 11/12

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, bouncycastle, java-11

I'm trying to do something that's supposed to be trivial but there is a problem that I'm facing.

The bouncy castle security provider won't load when after migrating a JavaFx application from Java 8 to Java 11 (tried Java 12 as well, same results). 
It's a Maven project that I updated to use Java 11 compliant plugins. It compiles fine but when running I get this in the terminal window:

> jar  .Launcher
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
>   Blockquote
>   **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**
>   **org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider**    at
>   .Launcher.main(Launcher.java:14)   ...
>   11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 12 more

In my java.security I have the bouncy castle provider as the first provider (also tried it as the last provider but the results are the same)

```
#
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
#
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.2=SUN
security.provider.3=SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=SunEC
security.provider.5=SunJSSE
security.provider.6=SunJCE
security.provider.7=SunJGSS
security.provider.8=SunSASL
security.provider.9=XMLDSig
security.provider.10=SunPCSC
security.provider.11=JdkLDAP
security.provider.10=JdkSASL
security.provider.11=Apple
security.provider.12=SunPKCS11
```

And in my code have the following (which worked fine when I tested  upgrading from java 8 to 9 or 10 in the past):

```
            //Since Java 9 we set the unlimited crypto policy in code, not by applying the JCE jars.
            Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
            //verify that JCE is applied

            // init the BC security provider
            if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null) {
                Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 0);
                logger.info("Security provider added successfully");
            }
```

The Bouncy castle jars are bcprov-jdk15on-1.61 (Bouncy castle provider version 1.61) and bcpkix-jdk15on-1.61.jar. The reside in the right place.

the command line I use to launch the JavaFx application is

> java -cp lib --module-path mods
>   --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web,javafx.swing
>   -jar  .Launcher
>   And ensured that the mods and libs are in the right place and accessible to the jar.

**I saw several problems in StackOverflow.com that resemble this one but tried the solutions offered and they don't resolve the problem.**

Any ideas as to why the Bouncy castle provider won't load and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your command line suggests you don't have BC on the class path. Have you tried a small test where you have BC on the class path to see if that works?

Comment: Thanks @AlanBateman,  The Bouncy Castle jars are in the "lib" folder so they should be in the class path. I'll run a test with an empty project , maybe it will shed some more light. I'll report.

Comment: You've specified `java -jar Launcher.jar` so the `-cp` option will be ignored. Best to start with a small test to make sure that BC is working before jumping to a complicated environment with both a module path and class path.

Comment: Tried it with the JavaFX maven sample project and it works without any problems. The problem must be something else.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem with a program of mine - works with Java 8 (and below), fails with 11.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should (if not already done) retry with BouncyCastle 1.66: it is a Multi Release JAR with a [module-info](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/ext-jdk1.9/module-info.java) which could help.

The dependency that I used:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>  
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>          
  <version>1.66</version>
</dependency>
```

You can enable debug mode for JCA using `-Djava.security.debug=jca` (see [Troubleshooting Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)).

For my test, I simply added a new line:

```
security.provider.14=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

In the `${JAVA_HOME}/conf/security/java.security` of my AdoptOpenJDK 11 installation. The BouncyCastle was provided by Maven as scope=compile dependency.

This simple code:

```
for (final Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
  System.out.println("provider: " + provider.getName());
}
```

Shows me that `BC` is loaded.

Also, if you ever need to force BouncyCastle as first provider, you will *require* `org.bouncycastle.provider` in your `module-info.java`:

By the way, your code is wrong: it won't insert BC first, but last:

```
if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null) {
  Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 0);
  logger.info("Security provider added successfully");
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Security.html#insertProviderAt(java.security.Provider,int)) state that `Security.insertProviderAt`:

> Adds a new provider, at a specified position. The position is the
> preference order in which providers are searched for requested
> algorithms. **The position is 1-based**, that is, 1 is most preferred,
> followed by 2, and so on.

If you pass 0, which is the same as calling `Security.addProvider(Provider)`, your provider will go at the end (see [ProviderList](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/jca/ProviderList.java#L112)).