# Globally register bouncycastle security provider in JDK 11

Tags: java, bouncycastle, java-11

In Java 8, I've globally registered the Bouncy Castle security provider by doing the following steps:

1. copy bouncycastle jar to `jre/lib/ext`
2. add `security.provider.<N>=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` `jre/lib/security/java.security`

Everything worked perfectly fine!

Now in Java 11, I've found `java.security` in `conf/security/`, which is fine, but there is no `lib/ext` anymore in Java 11.

What is the way to go to globally register Bouncy Castle in Java 11?

Comment: Did you look at [Bouncy castle security provider doesn't load under Java 11/12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437974/bouncy-castle-security-provider-doesnt-load-under-java-11-12)?

Comment: I checked BC 1.62 and it seems to work. Just needed to add bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar to the class path and edit conf/security/java.security to add security.provider.$N=BC (setting it to org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider should work too).

Answer (score 6):

So with Java 9, with the introduction of modules, you can place the Bouncy Castle jars in its own new directory or just about anywhere. You just have to provide the jar path in the --modules-path when u run jlink. Here is steps to build a JRE with org.bouncycastle:

- Download your JDK of choice (I chose azul JDK 11.0.12).
- Edit /conf/security/java.security to add BouncyCastle:

security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS
security.provider.3=SUN

…

If you append them last as oppose to first, the default SSL provider will NOT be BouncyCastle, which is fine but you will have to be exploit about your SSL provider when you get/initialize the default SSL provider.

- Download the BouncyCastle jars and place them in its new directory under the JDK directory
- Build JRE with jlink with following command from the JDK:

./bin/jlink --no-header-files --no-man-pages 
  --compress=2 --strip-debug 
  --module-path <DIR_PATH_TO_BOUNCY_CASTLE_JARS> 
  --add-modules <LIST_OF_MODULES>, org.bouncycastle.fips.core,org.bouncycastle.fips.tls 
  --output ./JRE_OUTPUT_DIR --ignore-signing-information

- Check that the bouncycastle modules are incorporated with:

./<JRE_OUTPUT_DIR>/bin/java --list-modules

It should list org.bouncycastle.fips.core and
org.bouncycastle.fips.tls

Comment: may you please let me know what should be <LIST_OF_MODULES> be here?

Comment: It depends on your build but if u are using/need java.util.logging then add "java.logging". ie, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/package-summary.html.

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to */{JDK}/jre/lib/security* and edit the file *java.security*
2. Add this line : ***security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider***. In my case it's 10 because there are 9 providers before it.
   Make sure that ***security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun*** is always number 1
3. Copy all Bouncy Castle jars that you use in your project, including the jars used by downstream dependencies, to /{JDK}/jre/lib/ext.
   In my case, they are **bcpg-jdk12-130.jar**,  **bcprov-jdk15on-1.49**, **jarbcprov-jdk15-1.40.jar** and  **bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar**.

Sometimes you may have multiple JDK versions on your machine so make sure that when you run the java applications, you use the JDK you just updated

Comment: [External jar support was removed in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B), so this cannot work.  The jar must be provided on the classpath instead.

Comment: And the folder structure jre/lib/security does not exist since Java 9. It would be /lib/security instead.

Comment: Even if this did work I don't think it's good advice (at all) to just copy your application dependencies into jre/lib/ext and have it affect all apps run from that JRE.